# Custom JSON array from Wordpress $wpdb->get_results array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

At the moment I have a JSON array of objects that looks like:

```
{
    "userid" : "3",
    "name" : "UP DISPLAYNAME",
    "usermeta" : {
        "nickname" : "UP"
    }
}, {
    "userid" : "3",
    "name" : "UP DISPLAYNAME",
    "usermeta" : {
        "first_name" : "Nicky"
    }
}, {
    "userid" : "3",
    "name" : "UP DISPLAYNAME",
    "usermeta" : {
        "last_name" : "PH"
    }
}
```

}

As you can see, it loops the same user multiple times, which is not ideal. What I wish to to is have an output looking like:

"userid" : 3,
"name" : THENAMEOFUSER,
"usermeta": {
    "nickname" : "UP",
    "first_name" : "Nicky"
    "last_name" : "PH"
}

But im bit stuck on how to do this - What I got at the moment is the following:

```
// select only columns you need
$sql = "SELECT wptest_users.ID, wptest_users.display_name, wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.user_id, wptest_usermeta.user_id, wptest_usermeta.meta_key, wptest_usermeta.meta_value FROM wptest_users, wptest_pmpro_memberships_users, wptest_usermeta WHERE wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.membership_id = 1 AND wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.status = 'active' AND wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.user_id = wptest_users.ID AND wptest_usermeta.user_id = wptest_users.ID";

$count = 0; // this is for $preJSON[] index

foreach( $wpdb->get_results( $sql ) as $key => $row ) {

    // each column in your row will now be accessible like this: 
    // $my_column = $row->column_name;
    // now we can do:

    $userid = $row->ID;
    $displayname = $row->display_name;
    $user_meta = $row->meta_value;
    $metadata = array(
        $row->meta_key => $user_meta
    );

    // now we can build a row of this information in our master array
    $preJSON[$count] = array(
        "userid" => $userid,
        "name" => $displayname,
        "usermeta" => $metadata
    );

    // increment the index
    ++$count;
}

// after foreach
// send the whole array to json
return wp_send_json( $preJSON );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few  things:

1) Doing another join with the *_usermeta  table is not necessary because WP has functions (such as  get_userdata ) that take care of that for you right from the box. I took the liberty to remove it from the QUERY

2) I commented your code out but it should be close enough:

```
<?php

// select only columns you need
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT
      wptest_users.ID,
      wptest_users.display_name,
      wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.user_id,

      FROM
      wptest_users,
      wptest_pmpro_memberships_users,
     WHERE
      wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.membership_id = 1
      AND wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.status = 'active'
      AND wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.user_id = wptest_users.ID");


$count = 0; // this is for $preJSON[] index
$user_object = array();
foreach( $wpdb->get_results( $sql ) as $key => $row ) {
  // "userid" : 3, "name" : THENAMEOFUSER, "usermeta": { "nickname" : "UP", "first_name" : "Nicky" "last_name" : "PH" }
    // each column in your row will now be accessible like this:
    // $my_column = $row->column_name;
    // now we can do:

    $userid = $row->ID;
    // $displayname = $row->display_name;
    // $user_meta = $row->meta_value;
    // $metadata = array(
    //     $row->meta_key => $user_meta
    // );
    $user_info = get_userdata($userid);
    $firstname = $user_info->first_name;
    $lastname = $user_info->last_name;
    $display_name = $user_info->display_name;


    // now we can build a row of this information in our master array
    // $preJSON[$count] = array(
    //     "userid" => $userid,
    //     // "name" => $displayname,
    //     // "usermeta" => $metadata
    // );

    $user_object[$count]= array(
        "userid"=>$userid,
        "name"=>$display_name,
        "usermeta"=>array(
          "nickname" : $display_name,
          "first_name" : $firstname,
          "last_name" : $lastname
        )
      );

    // increment the index
    ++$count;
}

// after foreach
// send the whole array to json
return wp_send_json( $user_object );
?>
```

NB: for the nickname I user the  $display_name But if it's something else, you can adjust the variable as needed!

Comment: Thank you for this :) However, im getting an error:
Call to a member function prepare() on null in D:\testsite\themes\twentysixteen\functions.php

Comment: Ahh, forgot the: global $wpdb;
But this leads to another error: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare() in functions.php  on line 574

Comment: oops...  Use  `$sql = "SELECT
      wptest_users.ID,
      wptest_users.display_name,
      wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.user_id,

      FROM
      wptest_users,
      wptest_pmpro_memberships_users,
     WHERE
      wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.membership_id = 1
      AND wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.status = 'active'
      AND wptest_pmpro_memberships_users.user_id = wptest_users.ID"; `  instead of what I had given before.

Comment: This works!! :) :) Have a function in functions.php that exposes a JSON endpoint for getting the data, as I need to connect to this from javascript....

Comment: Thx sooooo much